# Magento Mage::registry return NULL Value

Tags: grid

blow is my Block "Edit.php" file code.

```
<?php

class Matword_Students_Block_Adminhtml_Student_Edit 
      extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container{

public function __construct(){

    $this->_blockGroup = 'matword_students';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_student';

    parent::__construct();

    $this->_updateButton('save','label',$this->__('Save Student'));
    $this->_updateButton('delete','label',$this->__('Delete Student'));

}

public function getHeaderText(){


    // here i got a NULL VALUE
    var_dump(Mage::registry('matword_students'));exit;


    if(Mage::registry('matword_students')->getId()){
        return $this->__('Edit Studen');
    }else{
        return $this->__('New Student');
    }

}

}
```

below is my adminhtml.xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <matword translate="title" module="matword_students">
            <title>Matword</title>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
            <children>
                <students>
                    <title>Students</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/students/index</action>
                </students>
                <student>
                    <title>Student</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/student/index</action>
                </student>
            </children>
        </matword>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <matword translate="title" module="matword_students">
                        <title>Matword</title>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <students>
                                <title>Students</title>
                                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            </students>
                            <student>
                                <title>Student</title>
                                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            </student>
                        </children>
                    </matword>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

below is my layout config file student.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="1.0">
    <adminhtml_student_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="matword_students/adminhtml_student" name="matword_students_student"></block>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_student_index>
</layout>
```

where i create a mistake why i got a NULL on

> var_dump(Mage::registry('matword_students'));exit;

i follow [this tutorial for create a custom grid](http://markshust.com/2012/07/05/creating-magento-adminhtml-grids-simplified).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matword_students` registry variable `does not define`  **on that page**  why it showing the `null value`.

You need check it edit `form controller file` and on this `editaction`  function  magento `basically set registry variable`.

And that value is `fetch on  edit form  block class`**Matword_Students_Block_Adminhtml_Student_Edit**

**You need  editAction set it value:**

```
if($id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')){
    $Object=Mage::getModel('amatword/students')->load($id)
     Mage::register("matword_students",$Object);
}else{
}
```